# How to use Custom dimensions in libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar for Android app?

Tags: android, google-analytics

How can I use custom dimensions and metrics by using `libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar` and how can I view that data in my Google Analytics account?

I can't understand by reading Google's documentation.

Comment: Do you want to understand the usefulness of it or how to implement it?

Comment: Thanks for reply.I had implemented in mobile app but i can't able to view in google analytics account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view your custom dimension, you can add a widget in a dashboard :

`Dashboards > My Dashboard > +Add Widget`

Choose one of `table`, `pie` or `bar` widget, select your custom dimension in the green list and mix it with one or severals metrics to generate your widget.

For instance if you have a custom dimension 'age' at user-level scope, you can generate a widget with 'age' as dimension and 'visitors' as metrics to see the age distribution of your visitors.

Note that you can also create a Custom Report to see your dimensions.